# grep; Obtaining patterns from a file, Ignoring case

Tags: grep

I'm quite unfamiliar with Unix, and I am trying to understand how to perform `grep` through a list of text files, using patterns stored in a text file called searchlist.txt. The text file is a new-line separated list of names that looks something like this:

> "washington, martha"
>
> "adams, jane"

And I need to search for these names in some very large text files. I also need to ignore case. I've come up with `grep -i -f searchlist.txt *.txt`, but the only output I am getting looks like this:

> "adams, jane":"washington, martha"

I know for certain that these names are somewhere in the text files. I wonder if there is some specific way that searchlist.txt needs to be formatted? Is there some way I need to specify in the command that this list is separated by new lines?

Comment: Does your text file include the double quote marks? If not, please remove them.

Comment: Did the file come from a Windows or Mac system? If so, please transfer it using **text mode** and try again. Or convert it from Windows/Mac format to Unix format.

Comment: These two fixes did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file called 'needles' containing the following:

```
washington, martha
adams, jane
```

And a file called 'haystack' containing the following:

```
blah blah blah washington, martha blah
all work and no play
makes adams, jane a dull
girl
```

You should be able to use `grep -i -f needles haystack`.

If, however, 'needles' contains:

```
"washington, martha"
"adams, jane"
```

you will need to use `grep -i -f <(sed 's/"//g' needles) haystack` to strip the double-quotes off of the names.  Unless, that is, you want to search for only the names when quoted.

Naturally, this will not work for cases of 'haystack' such as

```
And on that day she changed her name to adams,
jane.
```

If someone on your list is inspired by The Artist Formerly Known As The Artist Formerly Known As Prince and has decided to put a double-quote into their actual name, you can make the `sed` a little more explicit and only strip the leading and trailing quote from each line with `grep -i -f <(sed 's/^"//;s/"$//' needles) haystack`.

Comment: This is great, thank you. In addition to stripping quotes, I'd needed to convert the text file to Unix format. Thanks again.